# How to share SVG styles with other users in QGIS projects

Tags: qgis, svg

So I'm publishing a project with web layers so that other people can just download it and do their work

Problem is that even when I save the SVG path, when I go back to the project, the icon does not appear properly. On new machines it just shows up a ? instead of the pins

is there a way that these can be integrated onto a project, for example by using a shared folder?

Comment: Did you save your layerstyle and the svg alongside the shapefile (ideally using the same name for all)?

Comment: @ErikLohmann no shapefiles, only WFS/WMS layers through geoserver

Comment: Are you using the qgis2web plugin? There's a discussion about using svg markers with qgis2web here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171728/qgis2web-fails-to-display-points-with-svg-markers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright guys I figured this one out by myself

On the project, opening it with notepad++ you get the following for each style

```
<symbols>
<symbol alpha="1" clip_to_extent="1" type="marker" name="0">
<layer pass="0" class="SvgMarker" locked="0">
<prop k="angle" v="0"/>
<prop k="color" v="171,26,184,255"/>
<prop k="horizontal_anchor_point" v="1"/>
<prop k="name" v=""/>
<prop k="offset" v="-0.11746,-1.99683"/>
<prop k="offset_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
<prop k="offset_unit" v="MM"/>
<prop k="outline_color" v="0,0,0,255"/>
<prop k="outline_width" v="0"/>
<prop k="outline_width_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
<prop k="outline_width_unit" v="MM"/>
<prop k="scale_method" v="diameter"/>
<prop k="size" v="7.4"/>
<prop k="size_map_unit_scale" v="0,0,0,0,0,0"/>
<prop k="size_unit" v="MM"/>
<prop k="vertical_anchor_point" v="1"/>
</layer>
</symbol>
```

All you need to do is replace "prop k="name" v=""/>" with the proper path, eg "prop k="name" v="N:/Systems/GIS/myawesomepin.svg"/>"

and voila, other users will have the pin loaded automatically if the N is the shared drive